# How does typescript check primitive type at runtime?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, compilation

I know Typescript stripes away any type or interface at compile time.
so how is it possible to check the object's primitive type using typeof keyword then?
Guess custom interface vs primitive types are dealt in a different way?

```
const a = "string";
const b = 123;
const c = {};
const d = undefined

console.log(typeof a) -> 'string'
console.log(typeof b) -> 'number'
console.log(typeof c) -> 'Object'
console.log(typeof d) -> 'undefined'
```

Comment: TypeScript erases the _metadata_ in transpilation to JavaScript, but you still have values at runtime that have types. `typeof` is a _JavaScript_ operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: note that `console.log(typeof c)` produces `"object"` and not `"Object"`.

Answer (score 1):

`typeof` is actually a [JS operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Typescript uses the power of runtime JS operators like `typeof` to do things like [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) at compile time.

For exemple :

```
declare const foo: string | number | Function | boolean

function bar() {
    switch (typeof (foo)) {
        case "string":
            return foo.toLowerCase()
        case "number":
            return foo.toExponential()
        case "boolean":
            return foo
        default:
            return foo()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPJjAJYoDm8APvCgK4C2ARiDNfAGJ0pgYmrsmeCCCgoAsACgp2br34p4TWAAoAlPADeU+LqIB3EhjAALeCowBPAA4gk2c7iRqN2yXo+IoaBACJiZOS++DqeYXAYdDCKTgB0GEgAMkj6rADC3iDqoWFgmfC+9MyswTlhehFRMXjxSACiAB7WqCAofFAQ2e7leT4FQkgiYqXd5RUgkdE4eGUeoNhQdBAYIaNj8JVTTl0eAL5Su0A)

Answer (score 0):

`TS` doesn't do any runtime checks.

What you're probably confusing here is that `typeof` is actually a `JS` operator.